# Ofmeet plugin token based authentication not working in openfire

Tags: openfire

I am working with ofmeet plugin in openfire for one to one video call functionality and i am following this link for video call like serverIp:portnumber/ofmeet/groupname -> http://serverip:7070/ofmeet/new1 working perfectly and i have follow this link using my mobile app display popup when i add a openfire registered username and password, it becomes a login but i need to token based authentication like not needed popup for userauthentication. 
please suggest me and give me step for any tokenbased authentication plugin in openfire + ofmeet plugin.
Openfire-version:- 4.3.2
Openfire Meetings:- 0.9.5

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue using either of two things

1) Enable anonymous authentication on your openfire server.

2) Write your own wrapper like I did in Pade and set username/password. See https://github.com/igniterealtime/Pade/blob/4259462f1d2129a4347eadbc1a57de4eaaab3e64/extension/jitsi-meet/chrome.ofmeet.js#L1028 2